# Address already in use - FastAPI

Tags: python, linux, ip, port, fastapi

I keep getting `[Errno 98] Address already in use` But the address is not in use.
I tried to change the ip and port but It isn't budging.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def main():
return {"message": "Helloworld，FastAPI"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
import uvicorn
uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

`uvicorn main:app --reload`
also tried `uvicorn main:app --host=172.0.0.2 --port=5000`
then it gives  `[Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('172.0.0.2', 5000): cannot assign requested address`
I tried running a flask dev server and it was also running on 172.0.0.1 without a problem?

using Arch-Manjaro-Linux

I used nmap to see what the fuss was about.

But only 2 ports in use on the [127.0.0.1](https://127.0.0.1) IP

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
631/tcp  open  ipp
8000/tcp open  http-alt
```

I would use another IP and port but it gives an error that it can't be assigned.

Comment: Run ss -lnp | grep 5000 to see the process holding the port.

Comment: it does not return anything. it happens with all ports and IP's. I tried running flask and I don't get this error when running on 127.0.0.1, 5000, 3000, 8000

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Basically, you can do this. This will kill the process that listens TCP connections on port **8000**

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the OS you are using, are you on a Unix like OS ? @RajathRao